# How to set a jquery cookie to stop repeating popups per user

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

So, If you go to my [staging server](http://fast-reaches-8304.herokuapp.com/) you'll see a mini tutorial I've added using [this tool.](https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS)

However, if you click on sign-up or any other page for that matter, the tutorial will keep popping up. So, how can I create a cookie so it only displays once per user?

I've tried [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), albeit, couldn't figure out how to get it working.

This is what I did:

```
1. Copied jquery.cookie.js into assets/javascript/jquery.cookie.js
2. Created a new file called cookie.js
3. Added this arbitrary code: $.cookie(guider, true);
```

Now bare in mind, I don't actually know what code I have to put in cookie.js to make it add a cookie for the guiders.js tool. So, that the guiders will only display once.

How do we get this to work as it should? Only display once per user.

**Guiders.js code:**

```
guiders.createGuider({
  buttons: [{ name: 'Next' }]
, description: 'Follow this short 7 tip tutorial and learn how to get the most out of Leap. It will only take a few minutes :)'
, id: 'first'
, next: 'second'
, overlay: true
, title: 'Welcome to LeapFM! Mini Tutorial:'
}).show();

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.title'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: 'The number of leaps a song gets determines how high it will rank on the charts. A song with more leaps will rank higher than a song with less leaps.'
, id: 'second'
, next: 'third'
, position: 7
, title: 'Tip 1. Ranking system:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.arrow'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: 'To add a leap to a song simply hit the up arrow. You must be logged in to add 1 leap. Users can only add 1 leap per song.'
, id: 'third'
, next: 'fourth'
, position: 2
, title: 'Tip 2. Adding leaps:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.title'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: 'You can view the songs genres within the parentheses'
, id: 'fourth'
, next: 'fifth'
, position: 6
, title: 'Tip 3. Genres:'
});


guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.song'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: "By clicking the song title you can listen to the song, comment on it and share it with the social media buttons. But dont't do it yet, lets finish the tutorial first!"
, id: 'fifth'
, next: 'sixth'
, position: 7
, title: 'Tip 4. Listening to songs:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '#query'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: 'You can search songs by genre, title or artist.'
, id: 'sixth'
, next: 'seventh'
, position: 5
, title: 'Tip 5. Search:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.left'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: 'You must be logged in to submit a song. LeapFM only accepts YouTube urls so your song must first be on YouTube.'
, id: 'seventh'
, next: 'eigth'
, position: 7
, title: 'Tip 6. Submit a song:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.newsongs'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}, {name: 'Next'}]
, description: "By clicking 'New songs' you will be able to view the songs from upload date (newest to oldest). Where as the default page displays songs by leap/rank."
, id: 'eigth'
, next: 'ninth'
, position: 7
, title: 'Tip 7. Newest to oldest:'
});

guiders.createGuider({
  attachTo: '.signup'
, buttons: [{name: 'Close'}]
, description: 'Sign up and start participating :)'
, id: 'ninth'
, next: 'tenth'
, position: 5
, title: 'Call to action!'
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a jquery cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285469/how-to-create-a-jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is your friend, and for non supporting browsers you can use the polyfill from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) :

```
if ( ! localStorage.getItem('visited') ) {
    localStorage.setItem('visited', true); 
    runMyTutorial();
}
```

Comment: You're the best man :) can you please customize the code so it works tutorial code? I've updated the original post with the guiders.js code!

Comment: I have no idea how that stuff works? I suppose you could just wrap all that code up in a function and name it `runMyTutorial` ?

Comment: ahh, just did that and it's still popping up :/

Comment: Well thanks anyway:), it seemed like the right solution but this is a tricky problem. I've been battling all day!